# Filtro de búsqueda Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

Estoy intentando realizar una búsqueda mediante filtros con tablas relacionadas.
Tengo una BD en Mysql en la cual tengo la tabla `polizas`, esta tabla esta relacionada con otras 5 tablas `ingenieros`, `tipospolizas`, `paises`, `ejecutivos`, `marcas`. Estas 5 tablas solo tienen 2 columnas, el id y el del valor.

En la tabla `polizas` se encuentran los siguientes campos: `id`, `ingeniero_id`, `tipospoliza_id`, `folio`, `cliente`, `paise_id`, `ciudad`, `ejecutivo_id`, `marca_id`, `modelo`, `numeroSerie`, `comentarios`, `pdf`, `fechaInicio`, `fechaFin`.

Cree un filtro que me traiga de la tabla los datos de acuerdo a lo que el usuario vaya escribiendo, el filtro funciona bien si en el filtro escribo cualquier valor de las columnas que no estén relacionadas con las otras tablas, por ejemplo `folio`, `cliente`, `modelo`, `numeroSerie`.

El problema empieza cuando escribo el valor relacionado con cualquiera de estos campos `ingeniero_id`, `tipospoliza_id`, `paise_id`, `ejecutivo_id`, `marca_id` no me da ningún resultado, pero si escribo el id correspondiente a la tabla de ese valor entonces si me da el resultado. Por ejemplo, el `id` del país México en la tabla `paises` corresponde al `11`. Obviamente escribir el `id` de la tabla correspondiente no es una solución.

Realicé unas pruebas con la tabla `ingenieros` eliminando la columna `id` y convirtiendo en primaria a la otra columna, la columna `ingeniero`, de esta manera pensaba pasar el valor del nombre directamente y la búsqueda funcionaría, sin embargo en la vista en el campo asignado al ingeniero me daba un 0 y al momento de crear también me daba un 0 cuando se desplegaba la opción para seleccionar al ingeniero.

Hice otra prueba poniendo el mismo valor de la columna `ingeniero` en la columna `id` y funcionó, podía hacer la búsqueda, pero el problema era que al crear una nueva póliza, seleccionaba al ingeniero asignado y cuando empezaba a rellenar otro campo el valor del ingeniero asignado se cambiaba al ultimo ingeniero de la lista, sin importar cual ingeniero hubiera seleccionado.

¿Saben de alguna manera de realizar la búsqueda/filtro con tablas relacionadas? He probado usando `DB::table` y funcionó, pero entró en conflicto con livewire al momento de usar los modales de edit y no me permitía crear mas registros, por lo que tuve que deshacer las modificaciones.

Les comparto mi código:
Componente Livewire

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Ingeniero;
use App\Models\Tipospoliza;
use App\Models\Paise;
use App\Models\Poliza;
use App\Models\Marca;
use App\Models\Ejecutivo;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ShowPolizas extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    use WithPagination;

    public $search = '';
    public $poliza, $archivo, $identificador, $folio, $cliente, $tipo, $ingeniero, $paises, $ciudad, $agente, $marca, $modelo, $numeroSerie, $comentarios, $fecIni, $fecFin;
    public $sort = "fechaFin";
    public $direction = 'asc';
    public $open_edit = false;
    public $cant = '5';
    public $b2;
    public $readyToLoad = false;

    protected $listeners = ['render', 'delete'];

    protected $queryString = [
        'cant'=> ['except' => '5'],
        'sort'=> ['except' => 'fechaFin'],
        'direction'=> ['except' => 'asc'],
        'search'=> ['except' => '']
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->identificador = rand();
        $this->poliza = new Poliza();
    }

    public function updatingSearch()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }
    protected $rules = [
        'poliza.folio' => 'required|numeric',
        'poliza.ingeniero_id.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.tipospoliza_id.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.cliente' => 'required',
        'poliza.paise_id.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.ciudad' => 'required',
        'poliza.ejecutivo_id.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.marca_id.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.modelo' => 'required',
        'poliza.numeroSerie' => 'required',
        // 'pdf'=> 'required|max:2048',
        'poliza.comentarios' => 'required',
        'poliza.fechaInicio.*' => 'required',
        'poliza.fechaFin.*' => 'required',
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->readyToLoad) {

            //<--------- Con esta sección de código realizo la busqueda/filtro  ---------->

            $polizas = Poliza::where('folio', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('cliente', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('tipospoliza_id', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('ingeniero_id', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            // ->orWhere($records, 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('ejecutivo_id', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            // ->join('ejecutivos', 'polizas.ejecutivo_id', '=', 'ejecutivos.id')
                            ->orWhere('paise_id', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('marca_id', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('numeroSerie', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('fechaInicio', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                            ->paginate($this->cant);

         //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        }
        else
        {
            $polizas = [];
        }
        $ingenieros = Ingeniero::with('polizas')->get();
        $tipospolizas = Tipospoliza::with('polizas')->get();
        $marcas = Marca::with('polizas')->get();
        $paiss = Paise::with('polizas')->get();
        $ejecutivos = Ejecutivo::with('polizas')->get();
        return view('livewire.show-polizas', compact('polizas', 'ingenieros', 'tipospolizas', 'marcas', 'paiss', 'ejecutivos'));
        // return view('livewire.show-polizas', dd(compact('polizas', 'ingenieros', 'tipospolizas', 'marcas', 'paiss', 'ejecutivos')));
        
    }
    public function loadPolizas()
    {
        $this->readyToLoad = True;
    }
    
    public function order($sort)
    {
        if ($this->sort==$sort) {
            if ($this->direction=='desc') {
                $this->direction = 'asc';
            } else {
                $this->direction = 'desc';
            }
            
        } else {
            $this->sort = $sort;
            $this->direction = 'desc';
        }
    }

    public function edit(Poliza $poliza)
    {
        $this->poliza = $poliza;
        $this->open_edit = true;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate();
        if ($this->archivo) {
            Storage::delete([$this->poliza->pdf]);
            $this->poliza->pdf = $this->archivo->store('public');
        }

        $this->poliza->save();
        $this->reset(['open_edit', 'archivo']);
        $this->identificador = rand();
        $this->emit('alert', 'La poliza se ha actualizado correctamente');
    }

    public function delete(Poliza $poliza)
    {
        $poliza->delete();
        Storage::delete([$poliza->pdf]);
    }
}
```

Para mostrar los datos de la tabla cuando es un valor de la propia tabla uso: `{{$item->cliente}}` y cuando es un valor de una tabla relacionada uso `{{$item->find($item->id)->paise->paises}}`.

Esta es mi vista:

```
<div wire:init="loadPolizas">
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{__('Sistema de pólizas')}}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <div class="max-w-7x1 mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 py-12">
        <x-table>

            <div class="px-6 py-4 flex items-center">
                <div class="flex items-center mr-4">
                    <span>Mostrar</span>
                    <select class="mx-2 form-control" wire:model="cant">
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    <select>
                    <span> entradas</span>
                </div>
                <x-jet-input class="flex-1 mr-4 input" placeholder="&#xf002;" type="search" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" wire:model="search"/>
                @livewire('create-poliza')
            </div>

            @if (count($polizas))
                <table class="flex-1 min-w-auto divide-y">
                    <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="cursor-pointer px-6 py-3 text-right text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider" 
                                wire:click="order('folio')">
                                Folio
                                @if($sort == 'folio')
                                    @if ($direction=='asc')
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-up-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @else
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-down-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-sort float-right"></i>
                                @endif
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Cliente
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Tipo de poliza
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Ingeniero asignado
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Pais
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Ejecutivo asignado
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Marca
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                Modelo
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                SN
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="cursor-pointer px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider" 
                                wire:click="order('fechaInicio')">
                                Fecha de inicio
                                @if($sort == 'fechaInicio')
                                    @if ($direction=='asc')
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-up-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @else
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-down-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-sort float-right"></i>
                                @endif
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" 
                                class="cursor-pointer px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider" 
                                wire:click="order('fechaFin')">
                                Fecha final
                                @if($sort == 'fechaFin')
                                    @if ($direction=='asc')
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-up-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @else
                                        <i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-down-alt float-right"></i>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-sort float-right"></i>
                                @endif
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="relative px-6 py-3">
                                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        @foreach($polizas as $item)
                            <tr class="text-left px-4">
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 ">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$item->folio}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$item->cliente}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900 text-center">
                                        {{-- {{$item->tipo}} --}}
                                        {{$item->find($item->id)->tipospoliza->tipo}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{-- {{$item->ingenieros}} --}}
                                        {{$item->find($item->id)->ingeniero->ingeniero}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{-- {{$item->paises}} --}}
                                        {{$item->find($item->id)->paise->paises}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                {{-- <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$poliza->ciudad}}
                                    </div>
                                </td> --}}
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{-- {{$item->agente}} --}}
                                        {{$item->find($item->id)->ejecutivo->agente}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{-- {{$item->marca}} --}}
                                        {{$item->find($item->id)->marca->marca}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$item->modelo}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$item->numeroSerie}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                {{-- <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$poliza->comentarios}}
                                    </div> 
                                </td>--}}
                                {{-- <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{$poliza->archivo}}
                                    </div>  
                                </td> --}}
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->fechaInicio)->format('d/m/Y')}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <div class="tex-sm text-gray-900">
                                        {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->fechaFin)->format('d/m/Y')}}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium flex">
                                    {{-- <livewire:edit-poliza :poliza="$poliza" :wire:key="$poliza->id"> --}}
                                    <a class="btn btn-green" wire:click="edit({{$item}})">
                                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-red ml-2" wire:click="$emit('deletePoliza',{{ $item->id }})">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @if($polizas->hasPages())
                    <div class="container bg-gray-100 px-6 py-3">
                        {{$polizas->links()}}
                    </div>
                @endif
            @else
                <div class="w-full px-6 py-4">
                    No existe el registro                
                </div>
            @endif
        </x-table>
    </div>

    <x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="open_edit">
        <x-slot name="title">
            {{-- Editar la poliza {{$poliza->folio}} --}}
            Editar poliza
        </x-slot>
        <x-slot name="content">
            {{-- Folio de la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Folio"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="text" wire:model="poliza.folio"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="folio"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Nombre del cliente --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Cliente"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="text" wire:model="poliza.cliente"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="cliente"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Tipo de poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Tipo de poliza"/>
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control w-full" wire:model="poliza.tipospoliza_id">
                <option selected>--Tipo de poliza--</option>
                    @foreach ($tipospolizas as $tipospoliza)
                        <option value="{{$tipospoliza->id}}">{{$tipospoliza->tipo}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-jet-input-error for="tipo"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Ingeniero a cargo de la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Ingeniero Asignado"/>
                <select name="ingeniero" class="form-control w-full" wire:model="poliza.ingeniero_id">
                <option selected>--Seleccione al ingeniero--</option>
                    @foreach ($ingenieros as $ingeniero)
                        <option value="{{$ingeniero->id}}">{{$ingeniero->ingeniero}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-jet-input-error for="ingeniero"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Pais donde se encuentra el equipo asignado a la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Pais"/>
                <select name="paises" class="form-control w-full" wire:model="poliza.paise_id">
                <option selected>--Seleccione el país--</option>
                    @foreach ($paiss as $paise)
                        <option value="{{$paise->id}}">{{$paise->paises}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-jet-input-error for="paises"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Ciudad donde se encuentra el equipo asignado a la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Ciudad"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="text" wire:model="poliza.ciudad"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="ciudad"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Ejecutivo que vendió la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Ejecutivo asignado"/>
                <select name="agente" class="form-control w-full" wire:model="poliza.ejecutivo_id">
                <option selected>--Seleccione al ejecutivo responsable--</option>
                    @foreach ($ejecutivos as $ejecutivo)
                        <option value="{{$ejecutivo->id}}">{{$ejecutivo->agente}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-jet-input-error for="agente"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Marca del equipo asignado a la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Marca"/>
                <select name="marca" class="form-control w-full" wire:model="poliza.marca_id">
                <option selected>--Seleccione la marca--</option>
                    @foreach ($marcas as $marca)
                        <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->marca}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-jet-input-error for="marca"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Modelo del equipo asignado a la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Modelo"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="text" wire:model="poliza.modelo"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="modelo"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Número de serie asignado a la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Número de serie"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="text" wire:model="poliza.numeroSerie"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="numeroSerie"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Comentarios sobre la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Comentarios"/>
                <textarea class="form-control w-full" rows="6" wire:model="poliza.comentarios"></textarea>
            </div>
            {{-- Documento adjuntado --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <form wire:submit.prevent="save">              
                    <x-jet-label value="Documento firmado"/>
                    <input class="w-full" type="file" wire:model="archivo" id="{{$identificador}}"/>
                    <x-jet-input-error for="archivo"/>                
                </form>
            </div>
            {{-- Mostrar previsualización del PDF --}}
            @if ($archivo)
                <iframe class="w-full" src="{{$archivo->temporaryUrl()}}"></iframe>
            @else
                <iframe class="w-full" src="{{Storage::url($poliza->pdf)}}"></iframe>                
            @endif
            {{-- Fecha inicial de la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Fecha de inicio"/>
                <input class="form-control w-full" type="date" wire:model="poliza.fechaInicio"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="fecIni"/>
                <x-jet-input class="w-full" type="datatime-local"/>
            </div>
            {{-- Fecha final de la poliza --}}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Fecha final"/>
                <input class="form-control w-full" type="date" wire:model="poliza.fechaFin"/>
                <x-jet-input-error for="fecFin"/>
            </div>
        </x-slot>
        <x-slot name="footer">
            {{-- Botón para cerrar el modal y eliminar lo que se ingresó --}}
            <x-jet-secondary-button class="mr-4" wire:click="$set('open_edit', false)">
                Cancelar
            </x-jet-secondary-button>
            {{-- Boton para guardar en la base de datos la información ingresada --}}
            <x-jet-danger-button wire:click="update" wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:target="save" class="disabled:opacity-25">
                Actualizar
            </x-jet-danger-button>
        </x-slot>
    </x-jet-dialog-modal>

    @push('js')
        <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            Livewire.on('deletePoliza', polizaId => {
            //window.livewire.on('$deletePoliza', polizaId => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: '¿Esta seguro?',
                    text: "No podra revertir esta acción",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        Livewire.emitTo('show-polizas', 'delete', polizaId);
                         Swal.fire(
                            'Eliminado',
                            'El registro de la poliza se ha eliminado',
                            'success'
                        )
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos.

Comment: has echo un dd() del query de la consulta  cuando usas cosas que no forman parte de la tabla creo que eso se debe a que son claves foraneas?

Comment: Que tal @ArcanisGK507 así es lo he realizado. Esto en lo que recibo
#attributes: array:17 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "ingeniero_id" => 1
          "tipospoliza_id" => 1
          "folio" => "1"
          "cliente" => "aaaaa"
          "paise_id" => 1
          "ciudad" => "aaaaa"
          "ejecutivo_id" => 1
          "marca_id" => 1
          "modelo" => "aaaaa"
          "numeroSerie" => "aaaaa"
          "comentarios" => "aaaaa"
          "pdf" => "public/1.jpg"
          "fechaInicio" => "2022-08-03 00:00:00"
          "fechaFin" => "2022-08-03 00:00:00"
        ]

Comment: ok aqui usan algo que se llama DB:raw para incluir esa busqueda en la clausula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507760/17161735

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 he probado lo que me compartiste, lamentablemente no me ha funcionado al intentar realizar el filtro, sigue sin darme un resultado.
Gracias de igual manera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto la búsqueda cambiando la consulta en el controlador:

```
$polizas = Poliza::select('polizas.*', 'ejecutivos.agente', 'ingenieros.ingeniero', 'marcas.marca', 'paises.paises', 'tipospolizas.tipo')
                            ->join('ejecutivos', 'polizas.ejecutivo_id', '=', 'ejecutivos.id')
                            ->join('ingenieros', 'polizas.ingeniero_id', '=', 'ingenieros.id')
                            ->join('marcas', 'polizas.marca_id', '=', 'marcas.id')
                            ->join('paises', 'polizas.paise_id', '=', 'paises.id')
                            ->join('tipospolizas', 'polizas.tipospoliza_id', '=', 'tipospolizas.id')
                            ->orWhere('folio', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('cliente', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('tipo', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('ingeniero', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('paises', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('agente', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('marca', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('modelo', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orWhere('numeroSerie', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                            ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                            ->paginate($this->cant);
```

De esta manera puedo consultar varias tablas a la vez.